# Moving from confide to Laravel 5 authentication model

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I'm upgrading my laravel 4.2 application to Laravel 5.

My project made use of the confide library for managing user authentication - with Laravel 5 handling pretty much everything that was provided by [confide](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) plus the fact that [confide](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) doesn't seem to be working with laravel 5, I need to rewrite my code to work with the Laravel authentication system.

Any pointers on what I should be looking at - I've noticed that the tables are structured differently and don't want a situation where I'll have to force everyone of my users to reset their account details.

Comment: Did you find out anything? I am in the same boat as you...only now Laravel 5.3 has "passort" to do authentication. I am wondering if I should rebuild everything in 5.3 or try and migrate users into passport.